# assembly error: "instruction operands must be the same size"

Tags: assembly, x86, mov

I'm very new at this and I'm trying to move values from one array to the other,
it suppose to be:

```
vec1 = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
vec2 = 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

but I get an error: "instruction operands must be the same size"

```
TITLE program

     .386
     .model flat
     extern _ExitProcess@4:Near
     .data

     vec1 WORD 1, 2, 3, 4, 5; original array
     vec2 WORD 5 DUP(?)
     .code                 
_main:

    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, lengthof vec1
    DO:
    mov eax, vec1[ebx]
    mov vec2[ecx], eax
    inc ebx
    loop DO

    push    0                       
    call    _ExitProcess@4          

    end   _main
```

please help.

Comment: related / duplicate: [Subtract a variable from a register? error A2022: instruction operands must be the same size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70911147)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I'd be looking at is the fact the a `WORD` is 16 bits wide and `eax` is 32 bits wide. So, when you load something into `eax` (without an explicit size specifier), you'll get 32 bits rather than 16.

In addition, I'm not convinced that your values of `ecx` will be what you expect - you should check that, keeping in mind that it needs to iterate from `n-1` down to `0` inclusive. The way you have it, it's going from `n` to `1`.

Comment: Thanks, that was the error. I still have some value errors but as you say it's MY homework :)
thanks.

Comment: +1. Very nice job of proving just enough info for a homework question. :)

Comment: This may be a homework question, but it might be useful for other assembly language programmers nonetheless.

Comment: Good point, @Anderson, since it's been _many_ months since the question was asked. Presumably, if it was homework, the student has either passed or failed by now. So I'll make the answer a little less obscure.