# Subtract a variable from a register? error A2022: instruction operands must be the same size

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

```
.data
    num1    word   0FEEDh

.code
main PROC
    mov     ecx, 0E4C7FFFDh   ;ecx = 0E4C7FFFD hex
    sub     ecx, num1         ;;;;; error on this line
```

I want to be able to subtract the variable `num1` from the register `ecx`, but that attempt gives:

> error A2022: instruction operands must be the same size

I am very new to Assembly and am trying to figure out the basics. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ecx` is a 32-bit register, a dword (double-word); in x86 terminology, a WORD is 2 bytes.
When you tried:

```
sub     ecx, num1         ;ecx = ecx - num1
```

The assembler checked label `num1` and found it to be of type `word`, and so tried to generate

```
sub     ecx, word ptr [num1]    ;ecx = ecx - num1
```

but that opcode doesn't exist.

A `sub r32, r/m32` form of [`sub`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sub) does exist, but loading 4 bytes from a 2-byte variable will pull in 2 bytes of garbage in the high half.

```
sub     ecx, dword ptr [num1]   ; don't *just* change to this
```

That would assemble, but you'd need to change `num1` to a dword for it to be correct.  (Unless you wanted to also read whatever 2 bytes you assembled after num1 into your .data section).  And if you use `num1 dword 0FEEDh`, MASM `sub ecx, num1` will work because it will infer the right size for the memory operand.  If you want to let MASM check your variable sizes against the way you use them, leave out operand-size overrides unless you need them (e.g. to copy 4 bytes at once from a string.)

---

The assembler recommends fixing the problem by making `num1` a dword variable or by changing `ecx` to `cx`. It's not wrong (`cx` can't store your constant but `masm` doesn't know that); however there is one other possibility. You can zero-extend to a scratch register and subtract that:

```
movzx   edx, num1    ; zero-extending load from a byte or word var
sub     ecx, edx
```

Or if `num1` is signed (`masm` has an `SWORD` but I usually see `WORD` used for both signed and unsigned):

```
movsx   edx, num1    ; sign-extending load
sub     ecx, edx
```

Comment: `sub     ecx, byte num1` doesn't exist!  There's no `sub r32, m8` encoding.  Are you maybe getting mixed up with `sub r/m32, imm8`, with a sign-extended *immediate*?  The only x86 scalar integer instructions that do sign- or zero-extending loads are `movsx` and `movzx`, other instructions need their memory operand to be the same width as the operand-size.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Stand by I'm gonna check what `nasm` generated when it successfully assembled that.

Comment: Note that this is a MASM question where `sub ecx, word ptr num1` is a memory source operand.  In NASM, `sub ecx, byte num1` is just suggesting to the assembler that it use an imm8 to encode the *address*.  The actual equivalent NASM instruction is `sub ecx, byte [num1]`, which won't assemble.  (Remember that bare symbol names are memory operands in MASM, addresses in NASM).

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yup just figured out I messed up.

Comment: When you fix this, I think it's also important to use MASM syntax throughout; especially since `mov eax, word [foo]` actually does assemble in MASM, with `word` expanding to a number 2, so it becomes `mov eax, [foo+2]`, which is insanely opaque and confusing for beginners that don't fully understand what `word ptr` does, let alone MASM vs. NASM `word ptr` vs. `word`.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I think I used masm syntax everywhere and accidentally fed masm syntax to nasm.

Comment: No, like I said, MASM requires `word ptr` as an operand-size specifier for a memory operand.  I edited to fix that for you.

Comment: Note on my previous comments: ECX is a `dword` register; `word` is 16-bit, so `sub ecx, word ptr num1` won't assemble.  (But yes, `sub ecx, word num1` in MASM syntax is equivalent to `sub ecx, 2 + num1`, which is `sub ecx, [num1 + 2]`, which requires the size associated with `num1` to match the dword register).